# Explanation of lmsensor output

Tags: kde, temperature, lm-sensors, widgets

I am using a small GUI widget that uses lmsensors to display temperatures of CPU, GPU, SSD, and other parts. But, you will have to manually select the device recognising it using its lmsensor name.

Please help in in understanding them as I want to add the temperature of my CPU and SSD in the widget. I can recognize the lmsensor for all other cores of my CPU, but I want to add the common CPU temperature.

[image: Here is the list of all source from which I can choose]

Answer (score 0):

Well, I expect:

- CPU package one of these (CPU model: Cannon Lake):

  ```
  acpi/Thermal_zone/6-x86_pkgtemp/temperature   
  acpi/Thermal_Zone/4-pch_cannonlake/Temperature    
  Imsensors/pch_cannonlake-virtual-0/temp1  
  Imsensors/coretemp-isa-0000/Package id 0
  ```
- HDD/SSD this one (familiar Western Digital part number)

  ```
  udisks/WDC_WDS100T2BOC 00PXHO 2118H 8443207
  ```

You may use `sensors-detect` to scan and get more details about sensors. Check its manpage.